Asymptotic behaviour of the difference process of the Polya urn
Assume we have a Polya urn with $(a,b)$ initial (time t=0) red and green balls, respectively. At each point in time we draw a ball at random and add it back together with further $S$ balls. This means that the number of balls in the urn after $n$ draws is $\tau_n=a+b+nS$. Let $X_n$ describe the proportion of red balls after $n$ draws. It is already known that $X_n$ converges almost surely to an $X_\infty$ which is Beta$(\frac{a}{S}, \frac{b}{S})$-distributed.
Consider now the difference process $\Delta X_n=X_n-X_{n-1}$.
Moreover, we know that $E[\Delta X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=\frac{S^2X_n(1-X_n)}{\tau_{n+1}^2}$.
Why does it hold that $ns_n^2\rightarrow L=\frac{ab}{(a+b)(a+b+S)}$? Here $s_n^2=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} E[\Delta X_{n+1}^2]$. I understand that $L$ is equal to $E[X_\infty(1-X_\infty)]$, but I cannot finish the argument. I am thankful if anyone can help me. Thank you!
